# Do not require tags when doing org-capture

Tags: org-capture, tags

￼
I have this org-capture template:

```
 ("a" "Appointment or call" entry (file+headline "~/todo.org" "Tasks")
      "* %? %^G \n %^t \n %i")
```

It asks for a tag. Sometimes I insert tags, sometimes I don't. In the past I could ignore entering a tag by just pressing ENTER. But from a point in time, Emacs shows me a list of tags I have used in the past and now there is no way to NOT specify a tag, because I can't escape that window. Any ideas how to use no tags?

Thanks!

Comment: Try `C-j`, which may allow you to skip entering the tag.

Comment: It's the %^G in your template that's doing the tag prompting.  Just remove that.  Look at the doc in https://orgmode.org/manual/Template-expansion.html

Comment: FWIW, I cannot reproduce it: ENTER gets me out of the Tags: prompt. What version of Org mode are you using? `M-x org-version RET` will tell. Please update your question with it.

Comment: @Dan I tried that but it does nothing. I still must press Enter to proceed with the completion of the template.

Comment: @gregoryg the point is to get the prompt but sometimes be able to skip it, not just to remove it all together.

Comment: @NickD I have version 26.3.

Comment: That's the emacs version: what's the org version? btw, what happens if you do `emacs -q -l /path/to/some/minimal/init.el` where the minimal init.el just sets up the capture template? does it work then?

Comment: org version 9.3.6. I will try that later.